# How to execute another action while one action is executing?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

My gui class extends `JFrame`. GUI contain two `JButton` say (start_button and view_button).

```
  JButton start_button;
  JButton view_button;
```

The action to be performed after pressing start_button takes some time(ranging from 2 min to 5 min).

```
  start_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //...
            //action executing. May take 2 to 5 min to complete.
        }
  });
```

While this action is executing, I want to see the status log of this action in separate `TextPane` enclosed inside `JDialogue`. And this `JDialogue` is made visible by pressing the `view_button`.

```
   view_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            myJDialogue.setVisible(true);
        }
   });
```

However I am not able to access any of the gui component unless and until the action performed by `start_button` is finished. And hence I can't check the live status log by pressing `view_button`.
How can I do so while one action is running ? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute your long running task in a separate `Thread` so you don't prevent the GUI from responding to events.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more information. Maybe a `SwingWorker` is the easiest approach as it creates the Thread for you and notifies you when the Thread is finished so you can update the GUI.